# Java Convert 8 bits string binary representation to byte and back again

Tags: java

I am coding an Huffman compression algorithm for an assignement.
I got everything working except the conversion of binary to bytes and back again on the decompression.

When I compress, I append all my codes in order to get a string like this for example: "01001100 10000000"

Now I want this in a byte array: {76, -128} with `Byte.parseByte("01001100", 2)`.

I end up with a text file coded in ANSI with `L€`

The problem is on the decompression when I have the text file above `s.getBytes("Cp1252")`.

I get the byte array {76, 63}, therefore I am unable to retrieve the binary code 10000000 required to decode my compression.

I expect to get {76, -128} so I can convert it into binary and replace it with the original message.

Comment: Can you please show how exactly you construct the byte array and then write/read that text file?

Answer (score 1):

To convert a `String` `str1` to `byte[]`:

```
byte[] bytes = str1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

To convert `bytes` back to a `String`:

```
String str2 = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
```

Instead of `StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1` you can also use another encoding or (as you did) use a charset name (`String`).